# Extracting date using regex on DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I want to extracted date from description column to another column. But, I have countered some issues.

This is my DataFrame code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'description':['description: kartu debit 20/10 indomaretcipete r', 'description: tarikan atm 20/10', 
                                 'description: biaya adm', 'description: trsf e-banking db 18/10 wsid:23881 riri indah lestari', 
                                 'description: switching biaya txn di 008 komp clandak armori', 'description: switching withdrawal di 008 komp clandak imori', 
                                 'description: trsf e-banking db tanggal :13/10 13/10 wsid:269b1 dwi ayu mustika', 
                                 'description: trsf e-banking db 1310/ftva/ws269b100240/home credit - - 3800372540', 
                                 'description: kartu debit 09/10 starbuckspasaraya', 'description: byr via e-banking 13/09 wsid46841381200 telkomsel 081293112183 tezar alamsyah', 
                                 'description: switching db biaya txn ke 022 danabijak tezar albank centra', 'description: kartu debit spbu totalterogon'], 
                   'label': ['minimarket', 'atm penarikan', 'administrasi', 'transfer', 'biaya', 'penarikan', 'personal', 
                             'fintech', 'other', 'pulsa', 'biaya fintech', 'fuel']})
```

and this is the what I have been tried:

```py
for date in df.description:
    date = df.description
    date = re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}', date)

    print(date)
```

But the output is **TypeError**: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Try `df['description'].str.extractall(r'(\d{2}/\d{2})')` ..?

Comment: In your for loop, the first line for each iteration is assigning the variable `date` to a pandas the Series 'description'. Don't do this - remove that line. Also I'd suggest giving your iterating variable a different name, instead of using `date` for example just use `for description in df.description: ...` then `date = re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}', description)`

Comment: @ChrisA This method is nice, thanks for the information.

Comment: All the answer below is correct. I love how @political scientist gave me a simple one line code yet it's answer my question,

Comment: how @Jaroslav Bezdek gave me an awesome function,

Comment: and how @Erfan taught me to split to 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To completely answer your question:

1. Use `str.extractall`
2. `Unstack` rows to columns
3. `Merge` the matches back to original dataframe

```
matches = df['description'].str.extractall('(\d{2}/\d{2})').unstack()
matches.columns = ['match1', 'match2']
final = df.merge(matches, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

**Output**

```
                                          description          label match1 match2
0    description: kartu debit 20/10 indomaretcipete r     minimarket  20/10    NaN
1                      description: tarikan atm 20/10  atm penarikan  20/10    NaN
2                              description: biaya adm   administrasi    NaN    NaN
3   description: trsf e-banking db 18/10 wsid:2388...       transfer  18/10    NaN
4   description: switching biaya txn di 008 komp c...          biaya    NaN    NaN
5   description: switching withdrawal di 008 komp ...      penarikan    NaN    NaN
6   description: trsf e-banking db tanggal :13/10 ...       personal  13/10  13/10
7   description: trsf e-banking db 1310/ftva/ws269...        fintech    NaN    NaN
8    description: kartu debit 09/10 starbuckspasaraya          other  09/10    NaN
9   description: byr via e-banking 13/09 wsid46841...          pulsa  13/09    NaN
10  description: switching db biaya txn ke 022 dan...  biaya fintech    NaN    NaN
11         description: kartu debit spbu totalterogon           fuel    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you, it is awesome to split it to 2 columns, I learned alot!

Comment: No worries, dont forgot to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) one of the answer @ebuzz168

Answer (score 1):

I think you are almost there. Just delete this row: `date = df.description` that is unnecessary and use `apply` function to get the dates to data frame column. Your code can look like the following (considering `df` is your defined data frame):

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import re

# define function to be used in apply
def get_date(row):
    date = row['description']
    date_list = re.findall(r'\d{2}/\d{2}', date)
    if date_list:
        return date_list[0]
    return np.NaN

# make date column
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_date(row), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) to have all possible matches in one column, joined by comma (by default it would be a list containing all matches).

```py
df['date'] = df['description'].str.findall(r'(\d{2}/\d{2})').apply(', '.join)
```

```
# output 
df['date'].values

array(['20/10', '20/10', '', '18/10', '', '', '13/10, 13/10', '', '09/10',
       '13/09', '', ''], dtype=object)
```

Edit:

Use [`str.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html), as @Erfan suggested:

```py
df['date'] = df['description'].str.findall(r'(\d{2}/\d{2})').str.join(', ')
```

Comment: Better to use `str.join` instead of apply: `df['description'].str.findall('(\d{2}/\d{2})').str.join(', ')`

Comment: I don't think I've seen `.str.join` before. Thanks, @Erfan! Edited my answer

Comment: @ebuzz168 glad I could help